# Serialize Selection shapes to .txt file by Vsto

Tags: .net, vsto, powerpoint

I want to select one or group shapes. Now, I know how to get selected shapes.

```
var selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;
```

the selection is what i selected. And i want to serialize the selection to .txt file. But there is a question,the `System.__ComObject` can't be serialized. So what should i do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerPoint objects don't provide any methods for serializing objects. But you can save the required property values as a text representation. So, later when you need to deserialize values, you can add a new object to the slide and set up properties according to the values listed in the .txt slide.